# msync equivalent in Windows

Tags: windows, unix, msdn

what is the equivalent of msync [unix sys call] in windows? I am looking for MSDN api in c,C++ space.
More info on msync can be found at http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/msync.html

Answer (score 1):

FlushViewOfFile

Checkout the Python 2.6 mmapmodule.c for an example of FlushViewOfFile and msync in use:

```
/*
 /  Author: Sam Rushing <rushing@nightmare.com>
 /  Hacked for Unix by AMK
 /  $Id: mmapmodule.c 65859 2008-08-19 17:47:13Z thomas.heller $

 / Modified to support mmap with offset - to map a 'window' of a file
 /   Author:  Yotam Medini  yotamm@mellanox.co.il
 /
 / mmapmodule.cpp -- map a view of a file into memory
 /
 / todo: need permission flags, perhaps a 'chsize' analog
 /   not all functions check range yet!!!
 /
 /
 / This version of mmapmodule.c has been changed significantly
 / from the original mmapfile.c on which it was based.
 / The original version of mmapfile is maintained by Sam at
 / ftp://squirl.nightmare.com/pub/python/python-ext.
*/

static PyObject *
mmap_flush_method(mmap_object *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_ssize_t offset = 0;
    Py_ssize_t size = self->size;
    CHECK_VALID(NULL);
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|nn:flush", &offset, &size))
        return NULL;
    if ((size_t)(offset + size) > self->size) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "flush values out of range");
        return NULL;
    }
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    return PyInt_FromLong((long) FlushViewOfFile(self->data+offset, size));
#elif defined(UNIX)
    /* XXX semantics of return value? */
    /* XXX flags for msync? */
    if (-1 == msync(self->data + offset, size, MS_SYNC)) {
        PyErr_SetFromErrno(mmap_module_error);
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyInt_FromLong(0);
#else
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "flush not supported on this system");
    return NULL;
#endif
}
```

UPDATE:
I don't think you are going to find complete parity in the win32 mapped file APIs. The FlushViewOfFile API doesn't have a synchronous flavor (probably because of the possible impact of the cache manager). If precise control over when data is written to disk is required perhaps you can use the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flags with the CreateFile API when you create the handle to your mapped file?

Answer (score 1):

Windows equivalent for flushing all filemapping is

```
void FlushToHardDrive(LPVOID fileMapAddress,HANDLE hFile)
{
    FlushViewOfFile(fileMappAddress,0); //Async flush of dirty pages
    FlushFileBuffers(hFiles); // flush metadata and wait 
}
```

And for flushing part of filemapping

```
void FlushToHardDrive(LPVOID address,DWORD size, HANDLE hFile)
{
    FlushViewOfFile(address,size); //Async flush of region
    FlushFileBuffers(hFiles); // flush metadata and wait 
}
```

This is described in MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366563(v=vs.85).aspx)

Flag `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` actually do nothing for memory mapped files (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)), also **even** file handle is created with these flags, metadata of file can be cached and not flushed, so FlushFileBuffers is always required for IO and MM, if you want to be completely sure that all data (including file access time) is saved. This behavior is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-caching)

P.S. Some real world example: SQLite use MM-files almost only for [reading](https://www.sqlite.org/mmap.html), so when you are using MM-files for write/update you need understand all side effects for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I suspect FlushViewOfFile actually is the right thing.  When I read the [man page for msync](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/msync.html), I would not assume that it is actually flushing the disk cache (the cache in the disk unit, as opposed to the system cache in main memory).

FlushViewOfFile won't return until the disk stack has completed the writes; like the msync documentation, it says nothing about what happens in the disk cache.  We should probably take a look at making that more clear in the documentation.

Comment: POSIX is [pretty clear on this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/): 'The msync() function shall write all modified data to permanent storage locations'. Thus, `msync(begin, file_size, MS_SYNC)` is basically equivalent to `fsync(fd)`.