# What is the approach to implement operator[] / iterator to deal with performance issue?

Tags: c++

Let's say that I have a custom container `MyList` like following.

```
template<class T>
class MyList
{
public:
    const T& get (size_t index) const
    {
        Block& block = getBlock (index);
        return block.get (index - block.startIndex);
    }
    void set (size_t index, const T& value)
    {
        Block& block = getBlock (index);
        block.dirty = true;
        block.set (index - block.startIndex, value);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Block is basically a cached block of data loaded from disk (there can be 2-3 such LRU blocks).  If a block is dirty, when it is not memory, then its data would be written to disk.

My questions are the following.

1. Overloading operator[] does not get the correct operator[] used.  I overloaded the following two:

   ```
    T& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        Block& block = getBlock (index);
        block.dirty = true;
        return block.get (index - block.startIndex);
    }
    const T& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return get (index);
    }
   ```

However, it appears that g++ calls the first one if the `MyList` is not a `const` version.  That is, for a code like the following:

```
MyList<int> list;
// ...
int myValue = list[0];
```

The operator[] called is always the first one which would set the dirty bit.  This is not what I want.

Did I do something wrong?  While I could certainly call `get()` or use `const_iterator`, my concern is that the user of the `MyList` would use `operator[]` in undesired situations.  Is there a better way of operator overloading that does not have this issue?

2. What about iterators?  I had the similar issue for `operator*` in iterators.  That is the first one is always called if the iterator itself is not `const`.

```
T& operator* ();
const T& operator* () const;
```

3. My goal is to run C++ STL algorithms such as `sort` / `nth_element` / etc on this container.  If we consider the search phase and swap phase of C++ STL algorithms, it appears to me that there is a potential for faster sorting if the correct iterator is used, if data is mostly sorted already.

```
MyList<int> list;
// ...
std::sort (list.begin (), list.end ());
```

Is there a way to minimize the number of blocks with dirty bit being set if the data is not changed?

Can you provide any pointers for what to look at / follow / learn?  Or is this a limitation of the language or compiler?

Comment: *"However, it appears that G++ calls the first one if the MyList is not a const version."* - That is how the `const` keyword works when applied to a class method.  During overload resolution the compiler will choose the appropriate function based on the const-ness of the calling instance.

Comment: in a non-const setting, `operator[]` is traditionally used for both _getting_ and _setting_.  That is, both `myValue = list[0]` **and** `list[0] = myValue`.

Comment: Off-hand: Return a proxy object that, when assigned to an object of type `T` unwraps via `operator T` (and never sets `dirty`), and when assigned an element of type `T` (`operator=(T t)` invoked) makes the change and sets `dirty`?

Comment: This is one of my gripes about C++: IMO there should be an `operator[]=` like in Ruby.

Comment: `const` functions are only called when the object calling it is `const`, or there is no non-const overload.

Comment: *"Did I do something wrong?"* -- well, "wrong" would be up to you to judge, but I will point out that Qt has faced a similar issue. See, for example, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932099) to a Qt issue arising from non-const `operator[]`. So at least you are not alone in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

The operator is called as per the standard.

To understand why: (with very few exceptions) all (sub)expressions in C++ evaluate exactly the same regardless of the enclosing (full)expression.

This means that the call `list[0]` is exactly the same in: `int a = list[0]` and `list[0] = 11`. So when choosing the overload for `list[0]` the surrounding expressions are completely ignored. The only things that are taken into account are the type of `list` and the type of `0`. Since `list` is non-const and a non-const overload with a perfect match is provided, the non-const overload is chosen.

So the problem in your case is that when you call a method on a non-const object there is no way to know if that will further be used to read or write.

Thankfully there are a few solutions to this problem:

### Return a proxy

Instead of returning a reference to the element, return a proxy object. Set the dirty bit only when trying to write through that proxy object. This same strategy can be extended to work with iterators.

### Provide a const view

Provide something like `std::span`:

```
std::span<const T> as_const_view() const;
```

This will implicitly enable the iterators you want. The downside is that the user needs to be aware of this quirk of your class and avoid calling `operator[]` for read access.

### Don't provide these kinds of overloads

Stick to `get` and `set` and avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Is there a way to use get/set interface to work together with STL sort/nth_element with minimal dirty bit set?  Basically the proxy approach?

Comment: @user1456982 either use `operator[]` `begin` `end` with proxy types or provide a const view.

Answer (score 0):

> Block is basically a cached block of data loaded from disk (there can be 2-3 such LRU blocks).

Assuming that you're using an operating system: The operating system already does all this for you. You already pay the cost of doing a variant of LRU replacement, buffer space management, all that - it's done. So you shouldn't be doing any of it *yet again* - what's the point? If anything, to help with prefetch, you should tell the OS what file location(s) you're anticipating to use next - if you have this information due to how your list is used. Other than that, just map the file to memory and synchronize it to disk forcibly if you think you need that for data integrity reasons. On POSIX/Linux platforms, you'd use `msync` for that, and there's [a Windows equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618046/1329652) as well.

> The operator[] called is always the first one which would set the dirty bit. This is not what I want.

The correct operator is called per C++ spec, so you do in fact "want" it even if you don't know that you do. If you think a bit about what purpose the const method overload resolution serves, you'll realize that doing it any other way would irreparably break the language.

If anything, you shouldn't be setting the dirty bit until something in that block actually changes, i.e. the block should be offering getter and setter methods to change its contents. An alternative, in your existing approach, is to allocate the memory for the block in a individually mapped memory page(s), load the block from disk, then set the pages write-protected. Genuine write access will trigger a signal (on Unix) or a similar mechanism on Windows, and you can then unprotect the page, set its dirty bit, and resume the program.

But that's utterly moot once you memory-map the file these blocks come from: the operating system does all the dirty-bit generation for you!

Comment: I am just using file to make the problem easier to understand.  The actual storage is something else.  And the OS layer cannot be involved.